# driver for RTL810xE

Tags: drivers, network-interface

I have r8168 installed which I have read is compatible for this device but it is not being accepted

```
 :> lsmod | grep r8
 r8168                 266240  0
```

Here is the device from `lshw`.

```
   *-network UNCLAIMED       
   description: Ethernet controller
   product: RTL810xE PCI Express Fast Ethernet controller
   vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
   physical id: 0
   bus info: pci@0000:01:00.0
   version: 07
   width: 64 bits
   clock: 33MHz
   capabilities: bus_master cap_list
   configuration: latency=0
   resources: ioport:3000(size=256) memory:91500000-91500fff memory:91200000-91203fff
```

Comment: Is it not supported via r8169 rather than r8168?

Comment: @Bib   Thanks. That works but I'm getting multiples of `PCIe Bus Error: severity=Corrected, type=Physical Layer, (Receiver ID)` Just a warning? But there are a lot of them.

Comment: I'd say that the card is broken, or perhaps the pci lanes to the chipset.

Comment: @Bib Ah that could be. I inherited the machine (people give me their old computers ) and it has a couple of bangs that look like might have shaken things up. Thanks.

Comment: Well pop it into another and see if it works, at least you can then isolate where the problem lies.

Comment: @Bib Good idea. It's a laptop so I'm guessing it's all in a piece but I'll take a look.